# Label with sub label in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to add percentages and sub-label under the percentage. I have tried different things but didn't work anything for me.

Here is my donut chart code:

```
   <Doughnut
      data={{
        labels: data.mainChart.labels,
        datasets: data.mainChart.datasets
      }}
      options={data.mainChart.options}
    />
```

here is the configuration that I am passing to that chart.

```
 mainChart: {
 
  datasets: [],
  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 66,
    spanGaps: false,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "right",
      labels: {
        padding: 16,
        usePointStyle: true,
        generateLabels:function(){
          const labels=["de 0 à 4", "+4j", "+15J", "+45J", "+90J", "+150J"];
          return labels
        }
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  }
}
```

Here is the desired output that I want to achieve.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem I found.

You are passing an array of strings to generateLabels().

But it takes a legend item as a parameter

> Generates legend items for each thing in the legend. Default
> implementation returns the text + styling for the color box. See
> [Legend Item](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface) for details.

So, you need an object with a few properties to get this going.

As an example,

```
<Doughnut
        data={this.state.data}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          cutoutPercentage: 66,
          spanGaps: false,
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
              padding: 16,
              usePointStyle: true,
              generateLabels: function() {
                const labels = [
                  {text:'dsfd'},
                  {text:'fsdf'},
                  {text:'sdfsdf'}
                ];
                return labels;
              }
            }
          }
        }}
      />
```

Comment: thank you sanish. Could you please help me to add a percentage above the labels?

Comment: Interestingly text is a string not a react component so I need to check if it's even possible.